# GC_FOR_ALLOC keep occuring and apps freeze

Tags: android, memory

Im new to android programming,  i have finished my first program. However, the program freezes after i running it and log cat appeared something like this:

```
05-21 14:41:24.853: D/dalvikvm(5024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 496K, 70% free 8328K/27200K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
```

I have searched through the net and they said this is the memory management problem. But what can i do to reduce the memory? I am using accelerometer and magnetic field sensor in my program, whenever i run that activity, it freezes. The heap size goes to 365M highest but f i don't run that activity, it will be working fine and the heap size will be just 1xxM.  Why is this activity using up so much memory? Please give me some suggestions.
Below is my allocation tracker and heap in DDMS.
[image: Allocation tracker]

[image: Heap]

Below is the activity that causes freeze:

```
    package com.example.suntracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Accelerometer extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    Sensor accelerometer,magnetometer;
    SensorManager sm;
    private int samintval;
    private float uxtemp,ux,uytemp,uy,ax,ay,axtemp ,aytemp ,sx,sy,axdiff,aydiff,latnew,latold,longnew,longold;
    private TextView showax,showay,showaxtemp,showaytemp;

    private float[] mLastAccelerometer = new float[3];
    private float[] mLastMagnetometer = new float[3];
    private boolean mLastAccelerometerSet = false;
    private boolean mLastMagnetometerSet = false;

    private float[] mR = new float[9];
    private float[] mhold = new float[3];

    private float yaw,roll,pitch,rollold,pitchold;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initialize();
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        sm.registerListener(this, magnetometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        loadsavedPref();
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
    super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    //  sm.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    private void loadsavedPref() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        samintval = savedata.getInt("samintval", 1000);
        latold = savedata.getFloat("latval", 0);
        longold = savedata.getFloat("longval", 0);
    }

    private void cal_displace() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //setting axis
        ax *=  (-1);
        ay *=  (-1);
        ax = (float) (ax * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(roll))));
        ay = (float) (ay * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pitch))));
        //
        ux = uxtemp + ax *(samintval / 1000);
        uy = uytemp + ay * (samintval / 1000);
        axdiff= (ax - axtemp)/(samintval / 1000);
        aydiff = (ay - aytemp)/(samintval / 1000);
        sx = (ux *(samintval / 1000)) + ((axdiff) * (samintval / 1000)* (samintval / 1000)) / 2;
        sy = (uy *(samintval / 1000)) + ((aydiff) * (samintval / 1000)* (samintval / 1000)) / 2;
        latnew = (float) (latold + (sy / 111229.0));
        longnew = (float) (longold + (sx / 71695.8));
        axtemp = ax;
        aytemp = ay;
        uxtemp = ux;
        uytemp = uy;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
          System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastAccelerometer, 0, event.values.length);
         mLastAccelerometerSet = true;
          ax = event.values[0];
          ay = event.values[1];

        }else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mLastMagnetometer, 0, event.values.length);
            mLastMagnetometerSet = true;
        }
          if ((mLastAccelerometerSet) && (mLastMagnetometerSet))
          {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mR, null, mLastAccelerometer, mLastMagnetometer);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(mR, mhold);
            yaw = ((float)Math.toDegrees(mhold[0]));
            pitch = ((float)Math.toDegrees(mhold[1]));
            roll = ((float)Math.toDegrees(mhold[2]));
            savePreferences();
          }
          cal_displace();
          savePreferences();
        }


    private void savePreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        Editor editor=savedata.edit();
        editor.putFloat("ax", ax);
        editor.putFloat("ay", ay);
        editor.putFloat("axtemp", axtemp);
        editor.putFloat("aytemp", aytemp);
        editor.putFloat("axdiff", axdiff);
        editor.putFloat("aydiff", aydiff);
        editor.putFloat("sx", sx);
        editor.putFloat("sy", sy);
        editor.putFloat("alatval", latnew);
        editor.putFloat("alongval", longnew);
        editor.putFloat("yaw", yaw);
        editor.putFloat("pval", pitch);
        editor.putFloat("rval", roll);      
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: The only thing I can see that would cause your problem is the preference-saving. You could try disable that and see if it solves your problem. If it does, consider calling it less frequently.

Comment: okay , now it can run smoothly, but how do i transfer my variables back to the mainactivity? any alternative ways than using preference?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of would be to use a `singleton` that your sensor-activity can send data to, and your main activity can read from.

Comment: I have searched for it , but i don't really understand how to use. Can u give me an example?

Comment: Thanks for the helps! I solved it by putting the preference into another activity then it wont be lagged anymore.